# how to check if an array has value that === null without looping?

Tags: php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php - has issues with that since it checks only by `==`. Is there any clever oneliner here that can do it by `===` ?

That is to return false if an array is empty, that is has 0 elements, or when array doesn't contain any value that is exactly null. True if array has at least one `=== null` element.

Comment: *If the third parameter strict is set to **TRUE** then the **in_array()** function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack*

Comment: Show your code. How do you call the `in_array()` function?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
in_array(null, $haystack, true);
```

If you read [the doc you referenced](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), you'll see that that function takes an optional third parameter:

> If the third parameter strict is set
>   to TRUE then the in_array() function
>   will also check the types of the
>   needle in the haystack.

Here is the function signature, specifically as it appears in the doc:

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.
```

Comment: @user393087: What makes reading an answer different than reading the documentation? It would be interesting to know (maybe also for documentation design, who knows).

Comment: I read documentation, but I just didn't see this part `[, bool $strict = FALSE ]` it didn't came into my brain like there was a blind spot in the eye.

Comment: @user393087: If you have problems to read things you can go through with your assistance.

Answer (score 8):

The in_array function accepts a third param (strict) that will do === comparison

```
in_array(null, $array, true);
```

Comment: For those who want to validate a blank field processed by JS before, change `null` by `' '` (empty space)