# Check if value is empty in a two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

How to check if a single variable or single value is empty
is array in a array or two dimensional array

**Like this array**

```
$resFirst=array(
    array(
        "course_name"   =>"a",
        "duration"      =>"b",
        "eligibility"   =>"",
        "recognition"   =>"d",
        "affiliation"   =>"c",
        "certificate"   =>"asd",
        "category"      =>"asd",
        "type"          =>"xcv",
        "school_batch"  =>"zv"
    ),
    array(
        "course_name"   =>"a",
        "duration"      =>"b",
        "eligibility"   =>"",
        "recognition"   =>"d",
        "affiliation"   =>"c",
        "certificate"   =>"asd",
        "category"      =>"asd",
        "type"          =>"xcv",
        "school_batch"  =>"zv"
    )
);
```

Or an array retrieved from database

To this, i want to check if `$value['course_name'] == ""`
without putting alot of codes

```
 foreach ($resFirst as $key => $value) {
        echo"
        <h6> name:</h6><p>".        $value['course_name']."</p>
        <h6>Duration:</h6>".        $value['duration']."
        <h6> eligiblity:</h6><p>".  $value['eligibility']."</p>
        <h6>recognition:</h6><p>".  $value['recognition']."</p>
        <h6>Affiliation:</h6>".     $value['affiliation']."
        <h6> Certification:</h6>".  $value['certificate']."
        <h6>Category:</h6>".        $value['category']."     
        <h6>Type:</h6>".            $value['type']."
        <h6>Category:</h6>".        $value['school_batch'];
    }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Just use your condition within if statement.

Comment: it would be so repetative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposition is:

Define mapping key to title row. For example:

```
$mapKeyToTitle = array(
        'course_name' => 'name',
        'duration' => 'Duration',
        ...
    );
```

Next step: change code responsible for out data:

```
foreach ($resFirst as $row) {
         foreach ($row as $key => $column) {
             if (!empty($mapKeyToTitle[$key] && !empty($column)) {
                 echo "<h6> " . $mapKeyToTitle[$key] . ":</h6><p>". $column . "</p>";
             }
         }
     }
```

Thats all

Comment: Alright thanks This is it.and this will be mine
`foreach ($resFirst as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $key => $value2){
            if($value2==""){
                $value[$key]="Field Not Set";
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if a variable is empty, like this:

```
if (empty($value['course_name'])) {
    // Variable's empty!
} else {
    // Variable's not empty...
}
```

Or, as Object Manipulator pointed out, just use `if ($value['course_name'] == '') { }`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. this is very useful for single dimension array. need to be improved for two dimensional

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($value['course_name']))
{
   // do somthing
}
else
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. this is very useful for single dimension array. need to be improved for two dimensional

Answer (score 0):

If you are PHP 5.5+, you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get all `course_name` in an array.

```
$resFirst=array(
    array(
        "course_name"   =>"a",
        "duration"      =>"b",
        "eligibility"   =>"",
        "recognition"   =>"d",
        "affiliation"   =>"c",
        "certificate"   =>"asd",
        "category"      =>"asd",
        "type"          =>"xcv",
        "school_batch"  =>"zv"
    ),
    array(
        "course_name"   =>"a",
        "duration"      =>"b",
        "eligibility"   =>"",
        "recognition"   =>"d",
        "affiliation"   =>"c",
        "certificate"   =>"asd",
        "category"      =>"asd",
        "type"          =>"xcv",
        "school_batch"  =>"zv"
    )
);

$course_name = array_column($resFirst, 'course_name');
```

then,

```
// if array has any empty value(means any one 'course_name' is empty)
if(array_search("", $course_name) !== false){
    // your code
}
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844573/861704
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

**UPDATE:**

I think I found a similar solution from one of the [comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#116635) in PHP Docs(its very similar to my answer though, just less code):

> in (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0) you don't have to write your own function to
>   search through a multi dimensional array
>
> ex :
>
> ```
> $userdb=Array
> (
>     (0) => Array
>         (
>             (uid) => '100',
>             (name) => 'Sandra Shush',
>             (url) => 'urlof100'
>         ),
>
>     (1) => Array
>         (
>             (uid) => '5465',
>             (name) => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
>             (pic_square) => 'urlof100'
>         ),
>
>     (2) => Array
>         (
>             (uid) => '40489',
>             (name) => 'Michael',
>             (pic_square) => 'urlof40489'
>         )
> );
> ```
>
> simply u can use this
>
> ```
> $key = array_search(40489, array_column($userdb, 'uid'));
> ```